# Python syntax error for (def init) function

Tags: python

I have encountered this problem while defining a class.

```
class Particle:
def __init__(self, (x,y), size):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.size = size
    self.thickness = 1
    self.colour = (0,0,255)
```

I have got the syntax error below when I tried to run the program with terminal,

```
File "3.py", line 7
def __init__(self, (x,y), size):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: As it stands, your code gives an `IndentationError`. Please correct it to reflect the code that you're working with.

Comment: Take a look at [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), which explains the problem you're having, why it's present in Python, and how to address it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't have tupple in arguments.

Instead, try this one

```
def __init__(self,xy,size):
    self.x,self.y = xy[0],xy[1]
```

and so on...

Comment: moreover you can also do the assignment in this way: `self.x,self.y = xy`

Comment: or rather *args and then self.x, self.y = args[0], args[1]

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your tuple (x, y) that way

```
def __init__(self, x, y, size):
    # rest of the code
```

or

```
def __init__(self, coords, size):
    # rest of the code
```

where `coords` your **init** expecteds it to be tuple of x and y coordinates. Keep in mind you got to change the access then:

```
self.x, self.y = coords
```

which is pythonish way to:

```
self.x = coords[0]
self.y = coords[1]
```